# How to run Dotnet run command smoothly using Declarative pipeline

Tags: asp.net-core, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins and the pipeline, I have created Web API and using Declarative pipeline to build and deploy the project on my localhost. 
I am facing an issue in executing the Dotnet Run command through my declarative pipeline, it works fine however it does not complete the stage (it keep running) and I have to manually abort it. 
The reason is because dotnet run uses Kestrel web server to run the .net core app.

Below is my script:

```
def BatchFile = "C:\\WorkSpace\\Thoughts\\DotnetEXEC.bat"

pipeline{
    agent any

    environment {
        dotnet ='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\dotnet\\'
        sln = 'C:\\WorkSpace\\Thoughts\\Thoughts\\Thoughts.sln'
        nugetexe = 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\NuGet.CommandLine\\tools\\NuGet.exe'
        packagedir='C:\\WorkSpace\\Thoughts\\packages'
        trxFilePath= 'C:\\WorkSpace\\Thoughts\\Thoughts\\ThoughtsUnitTest\\TestResults'
        mainDirectory='C:\\WorkSpace\\Thoughts'
        testResultFileName='UnitTestRestult.trx'
        publishDirectory='C:\\WorkSpace\\Thoughts\\Publish'
        webAPIProjectFile='C:\\WorkSpace\\Thoughts\\Thoughts\\ThoughtsService\\ThoughtsService.csproj'
        webAPIBuild='\\Thoughts\\Libraries\\ThoughtsService\\netcoreapp2.1'
        }

    triggers {
        pollSCM 'H/15 * * * *'
    }

 stages {
             stage('Checkout') {
                steps {
                 git credentialsId: 'be9c1836-afb8-4e2a-9f8a-96888c92c77d', url: 'https://github.com/gargankurg/Thoughts', branch: 'develop'
                 }
              }                 
              stage('Restore packages'){
              steps{
                bat "%nugetexe% restore %sln%"
                }
              }
              stage('Clean'){
                steps{
                    bat "dotnet clean %sln%"
                 }
               }               
               stage('Build'){
               steps{
                  bat "dotnet build %sln% --configuration Release"
                }
             } 
             stage('Test: Unit Test'){
               steps {
                 bat "dotnet test %sln% -l:trx;LogFileName=%testResultFileName%"
                 bat "copy %trxFilePath%\\%testResultFileName% %mainDirectory%"
                 }
              }                
               stage('Publish'){
                 steps{
                   bat "dotnet publish %webAPIProjectFile% --framework netcoreapp2.1 --output %publishDirectory% --self-contained true --runtime osx.10.11-x64 "
                 }
            }
            stage('Run'){
                 steps{                                     
                    bat "%mainDirectory%\\DotnetEXEC.bat"
                    }
            }
        }
}
```

### Here is my .bat file content

cd C:\WorkSpace\Thoughts\Thoughts\ThoughtsService
dotnet run --verbosity N

Comment: Your script doesn’t show a call to `dotnet run`. Also, why do you want to start your application inside of your _build_ pipeline?

Comment: It is in my .bat file which I added just now, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: My second question still stands though: Why do you want to run your app? And also, why do you run it using `dotnet run`, which will execute the development version of your app, not the one you published.

Comment: yes, the reason is because dotnet run will kick off the Ketrel web server which will allow me to use 5000/5001 port send the request to my app.